# issues with mysql GROUP_CONCAT and INSERT into another table

Tags: mysql, insert, group-concat, insert-update

I have a MySQL GROUP_CONCAT .... INSERT issue
This code works:

```
    SELECT group_concat(tabel2.img_name separator ',') 
    FROM tabel2 
    GROUP BY tabel2.produit_id
```

I need to insert the result into another table and I'm stuck.

This (or any combination I could think of) doesn't work

```
    INSERT INTO tabel1.imgname
    SELECT group_concat(tabel2.img_name separator ',') 
    FROM tabel2 
    GROUP BY tabel2.produit_id 
    WHERE tabel1.product_id = tabel2.produit_id
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabel1` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rubrique_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `marque_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subfamily_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `imgname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_description1` text NOT NULL,
  `product_description2` text NOT NULL,
  `product_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_min` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;


    INSERT INTO `tabel1` (`product_id`, `rubrique_id`, `marque_id`, `subfamily_id`, `product_name`, `imgname`, `product_description1`, `product_description2`, `product_order`, `product_page`, `price_min`) 
VALUES
(33, 15, 23, 40, 'product 1', NULL, '', '', 0, 0, 0),
(34, 13, 13, 13, 'product 2', NULL, '', '', 0, 0, 0),
(35, 14, 14, 14, 'product 3', NULL, '', '', 0, 0, 0);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabel2` (
  `img_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img_name` text NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `produit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_select` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`img_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4018 ;

INSERT INTO `tabel2` (`img_id`, `img_name`, `article_id`, `produit_id`, `product_select`) 
VALUES
(4013, 'acoacki086050.jpg', 13342, 33, NULL),
(4014, '32252il6jh2dqex.jpg', NULL, 34, NULL),
(4015, '33265ulrzmgr18w.jpg', NULL, 34, NULL),
(4016, '40334zcfk0c4n67.jpg', NULL, 35, NULL),
(4017, '40473frd4900u82.jpg', NULL, 35, NULL);
```

So for say tabel1.product_id = 34 I need to have tabel1.imgname = 32252il6jh2dqex.jpg,33265ulrzmgr18w.jpg

Comment: Please provider the full schema for tabel1 and tabel2, along with a description of what you want the query to do.

Comment: I saw the comment just now and I have updated my post with the said tables and what I need to do. Worse come to worse I'll export the concat as csv and then update just that column from a csv file. But I would very much like not to do that, especially since the tables are really large

Comment: You don't want `INSERT`, you probably want `UPDATE`

Comment: It doesn't really matter what I will use as long as it gets the job done. UPDATE didn't work either, I have tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the schema and requirements. That's very helpful. I have updated by answer with a query that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is `UPDATE`. not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE
    tabel1 AS t1
  JOIN
    ( SELECT produit_id
           , GROUP_CONCAT(img_name SEPARATOR ',') AS grp_img_name
      FROM tabel2 
      GROUP BY produit_id
    ) AS t2
        ON t2.produit_id = t1.product_id
SET
    t1.imgname = t2.grp_img_name ;
```

---

Random rants:

Why, why, why do you have these `table1`, `tabel1`, `tabel2`, `tableX` names? Names of any object (of tables, columns, indexes, constraints, databases) should reflect usage.
`table1` says nothing.
`tabel1` says nothing except that you don't spell-check your names.

It's good practice that columns used in Foreign Key constraints (and as a result for joining), have identical names (if possible). Not `imgname` in one table and `img_name` in another. Not `produit_id` in one and `product_id` in the other. It helps you, the next programmer and the guys who try to help you over SO, to not make mistakes writing `ON t2.produit_id = t1.produit_id`. It can also help, if you like the `USING (product_id)` syntax instead of the `ON` syntax for joins.

(update)
It seems that the different names are because the tables come from different sources/databases and it was not your choice. I would suggest you alter them to have uniform/sensible names, if you have a lot of work to do with them. If it's a one-time job, just to transfer/transform some data, don't bother.

Comment: Now I get this error:  #1046 - No database selected. But I will keep on trying using JOIN and see how it goes from here. Thanks

Comment: nah, that's too easy. Adding db_name.tabel1 and db_name.tabel2 results in #1054 - Unknown column 't1.produit_id' in 'on clause'.             Adding further db_name.t1 and db_name.t2 results in #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.t1 JOIN ( SELECT produit_id , GROUP_CONCAT(img_name SEPARAT' at line 2

Comment: Change `ON t2.produit_id = t1.produit_id` to `ON t2.produit_id = t1.product_id` and it will work.

Comment: ON t2.produit_id = t1.produit_id should have been ON t2.produit_id = t1.product_id, and, of course db_name.tabel1 and db_name.tabel2. WOW Thanks a lot! I am happy lol

Comment: yes I read it again and I saw that. Please update your post so it shows the right answer in case someone else needs the same thing.

Comment: @random rants :P tabel1 and tabel2 I spelled exactly as they should be tabel (romanian spelling) = table (english spelling). No, their real names are not tabel1 and tabel2 and so on to about 50, but I find it easier to use these non-descriptive names, so for testing purposes I work with tabel1, 2... 50+. I dumped the structure here without modifying the actual fields. So I have produit_id from a french database and product_id from the english one. Isn't it exciting? :)

Comment: @florina: If these tables come from different databases, that's a reasonable explanation. But table names in Romanian, some column names in English and some in French, is a recipe for headaches. I wish you luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO tabel1 (product_id,imgname)
SELECT tabel2.produit_id, group_concat(tabel2.img_name separator ',') as imgname
FROM tabel2 
GROUP BY tabel2.produit_id
```

**Update**: Thanks for posting the schema and clarifying the requirements.

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE tabel1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT tabel2.produit_id, group_concat(tabel2.img_name separator ',') AS imgname
FROM tabel2 
GROUP BY tabel2.produit_id 
) s ON s.produit_id = tabel1.product_id
SET tabel1.imgname = s.imgname;
```

Comment: I already have tabel1(product_id). And I need to UPDATE (? maybe) tabel1(imgname) with whatever the result I obtain from GROUP_CONCAT, applying the WHERE clause

Comment: I get error #1046 - No database selected on both your solution and ypercube's solution. And I am starting to feel kind of silly. Like I'm 1 inch from what I need to do and I don't see it.

Comment: As ypercube suggested, run this first: `USE db_name;`

Comment: Yes it worked. I have made a mistake when I added the db_name and (of course) it didn't work right away. I should have posted my question some time ago, at a reasonable hour and when my head was clear. Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify a value to insert

```
INSERT INTO tabel1.imgname
SELECT group_concat(tabel2.img_name separator ',') 
FROM tabel2 
GROUP BY tabel2.produit_id 
WHERE tabel1.product_id = tabel2.produit_id
VALUES('','')
```

etc

Comment: That syntax is not valid. `INSERT...SELECT` and `INSERT...VALUES` are mutually exclusive.